# Why do I have to put a variable using another "looping" variable inside the while loop

Tags: python, while-loop

Here is my code :

```
import numpy as np
i=0
liste=[2004, 2008, 2012, 2016, 2020, 2024, 2028, 2032, 2036, 2040, 2044, 2048, 2052, 2056, 2060, 
2064, 2068, 2072, 2076, 2080, 2084, 2088, 2092, 2096]
liste2=[]
while i<24:
    b=liste[i] +1
    liste2.append(b)
    i=i+1
print(liste2)
```

So I'm trying to create a liste that has the same values as the first one plus 1, so if the first liste is [201,206,207] I want the second liste to be [202,207,208].
I tried to put the variable b outside of the while but it doesn't work , so even though I found the solution I don't understand why it works that way.

Can you please explain ?
Thanks you for your time.

Comment: You don't need a loop for this at all: `liste2 = [x + 1 for x in liste1]`.

Comment: Where outside of the loop did you think `b` would be useful?

Comment: Use a for loop, a list comprehension or `map`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I didn't think it would be particularly useful, just that you didn't need to put it in there because the i is already looping inside the while

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The while loop executes a set of statements as long as a condition is true.
You are making **b** equal to the (element +1 ) No **i** from the 1st list. Therefore you have to keep it inside the statement because if you would keep it outside it will be no iteration of **i**.

Comment: Oh ok I get it now, I thought since i was looping in the while it would make b also looping whether or not it was in the loop, but it doesn't seems to work like that.                                       Thanks you.

Comment: You can accept answer by pressing V. By the way you do not need numpy here

Comment: Imagine your code had to handle not one but two, three or even more lists. It would be very confusing if every loop somehow automatically looped through every list at once, wouldn't it? In your very simple example it might be frustrating that you have to write so much code to do something obvious, but these commands are built to be as generally applicable as possible. One consequence is that Python very rarely tries to second-guess you (as opposed to MS Excel and, to a lesser degree, Python Pandas) ... if you want to loop over a list you have to be explicit about it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you don't, It will run forever,but you can also use a "for" loop like this:

```
import numpy as np
liste=[2004, 2008, 2012, 2016, 2020, 2024, 2028, 2032, 2036, 2040, 2044, 2048, 2052, 2056, 2060, 
2064, 2068, 2072, 2076, 2080, 2084, 2088, 2092, 2096]
liste2=[]
for _ in range(24):
    b=liste[i] +1
    liste2.append(b)
print(liste2)
```

Comment: You are iterating _ while using liste[i]

Answer (score 0):

Firtsly, If you put variable **b** above loop, in your case, python sets **b** variable only once, based on value of **i**.
During while loop you change **i** variable but not rewrite **b** because it out of scope. Simpler example:

```
lst = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
n = len(lst)  # n=5
i = 0
b1 = lst[i]
while i < n:
    b2 = lst[i]
    print(f'Loop {i+1}: b1={b1} | b2={b2}')
    i += 1
```

Output:

```
Loop 1: b1=0 | b2=0
Loop 2: b1=0 | b2=1
Loop 3: b1=0 | b2=2
Loop 4: b1=0 | b2=3
Loop 5: b1=0 | b2=4
```

Secondly, for your task you should use so called "list comprehension" - they are more compact and easy to read. Also, in your code you do not use numpy module, so there is no need to import it.

```
lst = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
lst_2 = [i+1 for i in lst]
print(lst_2)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```